# Where can I get ADT 0.9.6 for Eclipse 3.5?

Tags: eclipse, android, adt

I am having problems with Eclipse (3.5.x Galileo) crashing after installing `ADT 0.9.7`, so I want to try a downlevel version of the Android ADT (with Android SDK `r06_windows`)  to better isolate the issue.  When I try to 'check for software' at
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ I can only select 0.9.7?  Is there a trick to get the older version or an archive of the older version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download it from this [page](http://developer.android.com/sdk/adt_download.html). What crash issues are you having? Have you tried with the latest version of Eclipse 3.6?

Comment: I am getting the out-of-memory problem that is documented in the readme file, but changing the heap and JVM memory parameters only made it worse.  Furthermore, my downlevel to 0.9.6 failed even earlier in the usage cycle.

Comment: Weird. I've never had those problems. Have you tried with the latest Eclipse, Helios?

Answer (score 1):

I found it [ADT archives](http://developer.android.com/sdk/adt_download.html) http://developer.android.com/sdk/adt_download.html

Answer (score 0):

The android sdk website (http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) Will tell you not to install Version 3.6 of Eclipse but try to download 3.5 (Java build afaik)

> Caution: There are known issues with the ADT plugin running with Eclipse 3.6. Please stay on 3.5 until further notice.

Comment: I heeded that warning and installed 3.5.  My colleague is having success staying at 0.9.4 (October 2009) will try 0.9.5 next.